# Does there exist a power-summer of order $+ \infty$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

We start with some number $n$ and sum its digits (we can denote sum-of-digits function as $S_d$) to obtain number $S_d(n)$.

If $S_d(n)$ is prime then we calculate number $n^2$ and sum its digits to obtain $S_d(n^2)$. If $S_d(n^2)$ is prime then we calculate number $n^3$ and sum its digits to obtain $S_d(n^3)$, and so on...

We can call number $n$ a *power-summer of order m* if the numbers $S_d(n),...S_d(n^m)$ are all primes.

We can call number $n$ a *power-summer of order $+ \infty$* if $n$ is *power-summer of order m* for every $m \in \mathbb N$

A question is:

> Does there exist a *power-summer of order $+ \infty$*?

Are you of the opinion that there is some global maximum, that is, a natural number $W$ such that order of every $n$ is less than $W$?

An answer is not in my reach, I do not know much about sum-of-digits functions, but maybe someone has some good ideas.

[Peter](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82961/peter) found a number of order $14$, a number $20619661$ and calculated that upto $n=10^9$ there is no number with an order greater than $14$.

Comment: This might be an interesting question if you [edit] to include a short table showing the sequence for the first few values of $n$. Do that for several bases. Binary might be the cleanest - then you're just counting the number of $1$s.

Comment: What was the longest "chain" you found ? Or, as you formulated it , the largest order $m$ you found ?

Comment: Interesting question! To begin with, note that you are actually asking two things: 1. Whether there exists a natural number of infinite order and 2. Whether there exists an upper bound for the order of natural numbers.

Comment: @Peter I am not skilled in programming, I do almost everything on the paper.

Comment: According to my program, $$n=20619661$$ has order $14$

Comment: @Peter I think that is a very big order. Thank you for doing computations.

Comment: I will later continue my search ...

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος Well, if 1) is true then 2) is not, and if 2) is true then 1) is not.

Comment: Yeap, but there is also the case that none of them is true.

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος Ah, yes, that´s true.

Comment: Upto $n=10^9$ , there is no number with an order greater than $14$

Comment: @Peter I think there is a global maximum.

Comment: @Peter what did you use to run the test and how long did it took?

Comment: @Vepir Why don´t you chat with us? You could ask many more questions in our chat-room.

Comment: @Grešnik Which chat room?

Comment: @Vepir https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95333/discussion-between-peter-and-gresnik

Comment: The second paragraph (i.e. lines 4-5 including the empty line 3) of this question should be deleted.

Comment: Just two more datapoints: $14163804365$ for order $15$ and $30050544109$ for order $16$.

Comment: ... and $101171634764$ is of order $18$.

Answer (score 1):

Basic probabilistic heuristics suggest that there is no power-summer of order $+\infty$ nor is there some global maximum $W$.

If we view $n^m$ as a random number between $0$ and $9\log_{10}(n^m) = 9m\log(n)$, then $Pr(S_d(n^m) \text{ is prime}) \approx \frac{1}{S_d(n^m)} \approx \frac{1}{4.5m\log(n)}$. So assuming any slight independence between the events $S_d(n^m)$ (for $n$ fixed as $m$ ranges), which is reasonable, will give that the probability that each $S_d(n^m)$ is prime is $0$.

However, for any given positive integer $W$, $Pr(S_d(n^1),\dots,S_d(n^W) \text{ are prime}) \approx \frac{1}{4.5^W W!}\frac{1}{(\log n)^W}$, so since $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{(\log n)^W} = +\infty$, Borel-Cantelli suggests that infinitely many positive integers are power-summer of order $W$.

Comment: Can you explain this "Basic probabilistic heuristics suggest that there is no power-summer of order +∞ nor is there some global maximum W."?

Comment: @Grešnik that's what the rest of my answer does.

Comment: But, you assume that "assuming any slight independence between the events $S_d(n^m)$ (for n fixed as m ranges), which is reasonable,", can you explain why do you think that is reasonable?

Comment: @Grešnik I see no reason why the fact that the sum of the digits of one power of $n$ being prime should influence the fact that the sum of digits of another power of $n$ is prime. Of course, everything here is deterministic, so it is a bit silly to speak in the language of probability and hard for me to explain myself, but that is the best I can do.

Comment: @Grešnik But you are right in that I should say "basic probabilistic heuristics" under some sort of independence assumption. I want to emphasize, though, that such an assumption can be very very mild, given how low the probabilities involved are.

Comment: I understand you, exactly because all is here really deterministic, those events are not independent at all, you agree?

Comment: @Grešnik Well, it depends how technical you want to be. A very common heuristic in analytic number theory is that the events [$3 \mid n$] and [$5 \mid n$] are independent for a positive integer $n$. One way to make this (intuitive) statement rigorous is by taking a large positive integer $x$, counting the proportion of $n \le x$ for which $3 \mid n$, counting the proportion of $n \le x$ for which $5 \mid n$, and counting the proportion of $n \le x$ for which $3 \mid n$ and $5 \mid n$, and then noting that the product of the first two proportions is roughly the third (for $x$ large).

Comment: I am aware of some of those heuristics, but, the events that you assumed are "slightly" independent are not independent at all or almost-not-independent at all. I do not mean that this what I´m writing is easy to formalize and estimate, but, it˙s the truth, I think, as of this moment.

Comment: @Grešnik So one thing that "[$S_d(n)$ is prime] and [$S_d(n^2)$ is prime] are independent" could mean is that the proportion of $n \le x$ for which $S_d(n)$ is prime times the proportion of $n \le x$ for which $S_d(n^2)$ is prime is roughly the proportion of $n \le x$ for which $S_d(n)$ and $S_d(n^2)$ are both prime. The intuition that one being prime has nothing to do with the other being prime manifests itself in this notion of independence, a notion which will imply things I used in my heuristics in my answer.

Comment: @Grešnik Why do you think they are not independent?

Comment: Because n,n^2,n^3,...n^m,.. are, in somewhat free terms, completely dependent.

Comment: @Grešnik But once you start caring about the primality of the sum of their digits, I think the dependence of being a power of another goes away. I guess we just disagree.

Comment: Well, we do not disagree completely, just in some aspects.

Comment: @Grešnik Out of curiosity, do you think they are positively correlated or negatively correlated, or do you not have a guess?

Comment: To write you honestly, I am not so much into statistics and probability theory, and I do not know the exact meaning of "positively correlated" and "negatively correlated". If you can explain to me those terms in simple terms and very easily, I could be able to give you an answer.

Comment: In simple terms, two events being "positively correlated" means that one happening increases the chance that the other happens, and "negatively correlated" means that one happening decreases the chance that the other happens. One way to make this rigorous in the context of the question is to look at whether the proportion of $n \le x$ for which $S_d(n)$ is prime times the proportion of $n \le x$ for which $S_d(n^2)$ is prime is greater than or less than the proportion of $n \le x$ for which $S_d(n)$ and $S_d(n^2)$ are both prime.

Comment: Then, the numbers are both positively and negatively correlated, depending on where in the sequence we are exactly, that is my opinion, sometimes the chance will increase and sometimes decrease. Of course, I do not mean that the same "small" event in the same sense and same context will be simultaneously both positively and negatively correlated, but that the pairs of numbers (n^m,n^k) will have a very very interesting pattern of correlations when we vary m,k.

Comment: I did not express myself very precisely, but, I think you understand what I mean.

Comment: @Grešnik if that is what you believe, then you should be led to the same conclusion as myself that there is no power-summer of order $+\infty$. Note that I didn't need independence; if there is sometimes negative correlation, that suffices as well. In fact, as long as there is not insane positive correlation, there will be no power-summer of order $+\infty$.