# determine whether it is possible that $a_n$ is composite only finitely many times

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, divisibility

> Form a sequence $(a_n)$ as follows: Let $a_1$ be any positive integer. Let $a_{n+1}$ be formed from $a_n$ by appending any decimal digit to the end of $a_1$. Determine, with proof, whether it is possible that $a_n$ is composite only finitely often (i.e. if there exists a value of $a_1$ that makes $a_n$ composite only finitely often).

- The digits $0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8$ can only be used finitely many times as otherwise one would get infinitely many composites.
- The digits $1, 7$ can only be used finitely many times as, after we stop using $2, 5$ and $8$, they are the only ones to change the remainder modulo $3$ and both add $1$ to it (otherwise there would be infinitely many multiples of $3$).
- Both $3$ and $9$ must be used infinitely many times because, if at some point a prime $p$ is reached, adding at most $p$ of the same digit yields another multiple of $p$.

Even with these restrictions the question seems very hard. For instance, the following are primes of length $9$: $1979339333, 1979339339$.

Comment: I assume that the second line should read "... to the end of $a_n$", right? And... what is the source of the problem?

Comment: With a decent amount of work modulo $7$ (but without many new ideas), one can show that such an infinite sequence with finitely many primes must eventually be $5\pmod 7$ infinitely often, and the possible "moves" are adding $93$, $339$, or $9939$ (each of which preserves $5\pmod 7$-ness). Not sure this is actually helpful.

Comment: Do you mean "infinite many composites" instead of "infinite many primes" ? Since adding a digit different from $1,3,7,9$ leads to a composite. Hard to imagine that the number of composites can be finite. This would mean that there is a start value allowing ONLY primes. Maybe this can be even refuted, but it is at least very hard to imagine.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncatable_prime

Comment: Somewhat related, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3264921/extending-prime-numbers-digit-by-digit-while-retaining-primality

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem **Growing Primes #1** posed by Frank Rubin in [his website](http://www.contestcen.com/digits.htm).

A discussion about it (with no solution) may be found [here](https://www.primepuzzles.net/puzzles/puzz_131.htm).

As far as I am aware, there is no evidence anybody but Rubin was able to solve it, so you might want to ask him for his proof.

[This article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.14932.pdf) discusses the problem and suggests it might be open still.